# Anaconda Prompt "Failed to create temp directory"

Tags: python, anaconda

**My Issue**
I recently installed Anaconda3-2020.07 on Windows 10 but am having a lot of issues. I think it is related to the fact I idiotically put a space in my username.

1. When I try to launch `Anaconda Navigator`, nothing happens
2. When I launch `Ananconda Powershell Prompt` I get this error

```
failed to create process.
Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is
an empty string.
At C:\Users\Patrick Wong\anaconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1:101 char:36
+         Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterB
   indingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAl
   lowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

3. When I launch Anaconda Prompt I get this error

```
Failed to create temp directory "C:\Users\Patrick Wong\AppData\Local\Temp\conda-<RANDOM>\"
```

4. When I launch Jupyter Notebook, everything seems fine though.

**What I've tried**

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling doesn't work
2. `conda update` results in `conda is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
3. I've navigated to `anaconda3/Scripts` on my cmd and have tried running `conda update` which results in `failed to create process`
4. I've considered reassigning the Env Variables TEMP, TMP but I'm quite hesitant as I'm not sure if this has potential future repercussions

From what I understand, the white space in the windows username is a longstanding issue with anaconda, but anaconda has worked for me before. It only recently broke, after I stopped using it for about 3 months.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Patrick, have you tried re-installing into some directory that's not your user homedir, to make sure it's not related to something else on your system?

Comment: Hey Peter. Thanks for your suggestion. I installed it in OS (C:) and now everything seems ok (except for anaconda prompt, but that's good enough for now).

Answer (score 0):

When I have this issue it is because Anaconda has left a file behind in this location C:\Users that directory normally has only the Users' folder(s) as it is normally empty
so if you see a file without an extension delete it and run the process again, and it should function as expected.

In this Pic it shows a file AFFA that was left behind by Anaconda yours will likely be a different name just delete the file(s) usually only 1 file.

Viola [image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix, switch off `Windows 10 Ransomware protection`:

- Windows key, then search for `Ransomeware Protection`.
- Under `Controlling folder access`, switch off.
- Alternatively, remove any controlled folders that might be including that temporary directory.

Can also replicate this by attempting to create a folder within `C:\Users\Patrick Wong\AppData\Local\Temp\` using the shell command `mkdir x`, it will fail with an obscure error. Using `mkdir x` anywhere else will work fine.

Issue started to appear when Windows 10 x64 upgraded to 21H2 (OS Build 19044.1741). I'm all for Ransomware protection, but not if it completely destroys a PC as far as legitimate use goes.